# Airplay mirroring from Ubuntu 16.04 to Apple TV

Tags: airplay

In our company we are using Apple TV's and we want to provide the possibility to mirror from every device, Mac and Windows are not a problem but I cannot find the way to do it for Ubuntu 16.04, does anybody knows how?

Comment: Does this http://www.instructables.com/id/Airplay-to-AppleTV-From-Linux-PC/step3/Executing-in-Terminal/ help? I have no hardware to check.

Comment: Seems to work if you set a password on the apple tv. I was not able to run it without password configured.

Answer (score 8):

You will need several things:

1. IP address for Apple TV
2. Airplay.jar from https://github.com/jamesdlow/open-airplay/releases
3. Properly installed java (to execute jar file from your terminal)

Here is one way you can tell if you're Apple TV is detectable by your computer on the network:

`ping appletv.local`

Ok, next step is to execute `airplay.jar` from a terminal (do this from a directory which contains jar):

`java -jar airplay.jar -h 172.18.129.223 -d`

If your appleTV device has some credentials you can use

`java -jar airplay.jar -h hostname[:port] [-a password] -d`

The most important thing to note is that it is not true airplay screen sharing, it is emulated through taking screenshots of your desktop each second and sending it to AppleTV as a photo. However, it is the best way I know to deal with screen sharing to AppleTV from a non-apple device. (Proprietary sucks!)

You can also find a list of other libraries to work with AppleTV here:
https://github.com/jamesdlow/open-airplay

That's it! Now you should see your screen on the AppleTV.

Credit to [Vadim Kirilchuk's blogspot](http://vadim-kirilchuk-linux.blogspot.com/2013/07/share-screen-to-appletv-from-linux.html)

Comment: My friend's Apple's TV says that iOS +7.1 is required. Looks like the the last version in github is not compatible with current AppleTV.

Comment: Does this still work?  It seems to have some problems